# Access Violation Error only when running user service account

Tags: c#, c, dllimport

In our existing application we are using a windows service which has a DLL import to call some functions in native assembly. This has been working fine as long as the service where this native function is called is running as Network Service. It also works when the service runs as LocalSystem.

In order to set customized privileges , we have decided to add support for using a Service account. However simply running the service as a newly created windows user account results in Access Violation error during the Native method call.

Similarly, I tried with a domain account which has administrator permissions on the system to run the service, but still it results in the same problem.

I cannot find any documentation on MSDN where specific permission for user account are listed for DLL Import to work. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

C# Code

```
[DllImport("lmgr11.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public static extern string GetFeaturelist(short jobType, int flag);
```

C Code

```
char* WINAPI GetFeaturelist(int type, int flag)
{
    char * featureList;
    char ** features, ** tempFeatureList;
    int counter = 0;

    if (!lm_job)
    {   
        return NULL;
    }

    features = tempFeatureList = lc_feat_list(lm_job,flag,NULL);

    //loop to know the number of features
    while(*tempFeatureList != NULL)
    { 
        counter++;
        tempFeatureList++;
    }

    featureList =  (char*) CoTaskMemAlloc(counter * 50);
    strcpy(featureList,"");

    while(*features != NULL)
    {
        strcat(featureList,*features);   
        strcat(featureList,"$$&&#&&$$");
        features++;
    }
    lc_log(lm_job, featureList);
    return featureList; 
}
```

Comment: Do some debugging. For all we know, the exception occurs in that C code. After all, that hard coded 50 seems like it could be a risk. And some of the error checking in there looks dubious. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for debugging. Perhaps you haven't done any debugging because the code runs in a service context that you can't attach the VS debugger to. Fine. Use trace debugging.

Comment: The dll will be running with the user environment (including credentials).  You need to set the role properly on server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: hello. did you compile lmgr11.dll this dll yourself? Do you have any documentation on how to do it?

Comment: @Barış Akkurt
Yes, I compiled with the nmake command with Visual Studio. The supported visual studio version changes depending upon the Flexera version you are using. I no longer have access to the documentation, but you can research based on the below flexera link : https://community.flexera.com/t5/FlexNet-Publisher-Knowledge-Base/Enabling-Native-HostID-support-with-Java-Based-FNP-applications/ta-p/169322

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that "featurelist" variable in the C code was null, and the below code was not enough to handle it.

```
while(*features != NULL)
```

Adding another check using the below code, avoids the crash.

```
features != NULL
```

As for the error occurring only when not running as "Network Service", the 3rd Party code (lc_feat_list) depended on an user specific registry entry in HKU, whereas the documentation incorrectly refers to a static registry entry under HKLM, which ultimately caused it to return a null value.